# picking django template variable from rendered template to use in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-templates

I am still new to django and struggling with this issue : I have a price slidebar in html that i picked up from a template.
In html, the bar looks like this :

```
    <div class="price-range ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content"
                    data-min="33"" <!-- to replace with :{{price_max.product_price__max }}" -->
                    data-max="15"
                  ></div>
                  <div class="range-slider">
                    <div class="price-input">
                      <p>Prix:</p>
                      <input type="text" id="minamount" />
                      <input type="text" id="maxamount" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Filter</a>
```

I upload price_max and also price_min correctly from the view as they can be directly displayed on the webpage as text. But the slidebar uses javascript to be rendered and picks up those data-min and data-max values to display  the dynamic result like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRc22.jpg)

the javascript:

```
    /*-------------------
        Range Slider
    --------------------- */
    var rangeSlider = $(".price-range"),
    minamount = $("#minamount"),
    maxamount = $("#maxamount"),
    minPrice = rangeSlider.data('min'),
    maxPrice = rangeSlider.data('max');
    rangeSlider.slider({
    range: true,
    min: minPrice,
    max: maxPrice,
    values: [minPrice, maxPrice],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        minamount.val( ui.values[0]+'€');
        maxamount.val( ui.values[1]+'€');
        }
    });
    minamount.val( rangeSlider.slider("values", 0)+'€');
    maxamount.val( rangeSlider.slider("values", 1)+'€');
```

replacing data-min and data-max by django templates variables doesn't work, i'm still unclear exactly why but i suppose it has to do with django rendering order. Another difficulty is that i would like to replace the html rendered values by the one picked by the user, and then get thos values to reuse them in my javascript filter product file.

-How should i proceed to render data_min / data_max with the view injected values?

i was expecting the django variable to be displayed in the html attributes of the input, then to be reused by javascript and to be rerendered as it does when the values are written as plain numbers in the html.
I don't understand why it doesn't work since the django templates variables can be displayed in plain text like this `<p>{{ price_max }}</p>`, so the arbitrary numbers for data-min and data-max are succesfully replaced when the html is produced.

edit: rendered html :

```
                <div class="filter-range-wrap">
              <div class="filter-range-wrap">
                <div class="price-range ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content"
                data-min="" data-max="99"></div>
                <div class="range-slider">
                    <div class="price-input">
                        <p>Price:</p>
                        <input type="text" id="minamount">
                        <input type="text" id="maxamount">
                    </div>
```

initial template code:

```
                <div class="filter-range-wrap">
              <div class="filter-range-wrap">
                <div class="price-range ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content"
                data-min="{{minMaxPrice.price__min}}" data-max="99"></div>
                <div class="range-slider">
                    <div class="price-input">
                        <p>Price:</p>
                        <input type="text" id="minamount">
                        <input type="text" id="maxamount">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hi, try putting your jquery code inside `$(document).ready..` or `$(window).load..` this make sure your DOM is loaded and then it will try to initialise your slider. Read [this](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

"i was expecting the django variable to be displayed in the html attributes of the input, then to be reused by javascript and to be rerendered as it does when the values are written as plain numbers in the html"

This is how it works. I think there is some js syntax/type rendering problem (m.b. quotes or something). Can you provide rendered html code and template code?

Comment: i added the rendered html and the template code, did you mean the full template html file?

Comment: it looks like variable minMaxPrice not in context or price__min not defined.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups